# Pass Print messages in Python to email

Tags: python

I've written a python script that has several print statements in it. I'd like to pass these print statements to an email that the script will send me after it has finished running. Is this possible?

Below is my attempt, it errors out at the deleted =

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.DeleteRows_management(r"C:\GIS_Work\StreetsTesting\Lake George.shp")

deleted = print "The rows have been deleted from Lake George"

# Send Email when script is complete
SERVER = "my.mailserver.com"
FROM = "from@email.com>"
TO = "to@email.com>"
SUBJECT = "The Script Has Completed"
MSG = deleted

# Prepare actual message
MESSAGE = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, MSG)

# Send the mail
server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MESSAGE)
server.quit()
```

Comment: What? Why can't you just use the string, like you do everywhere else?

Comment: bad example. I've edited. I just want it to pass the print statements so that I know each step has completed.

Comment: Well, my question still stands. Why can't you assign the message to a string, print that, then add the same string to the email?

Comment: so the only change you need is
`deleted = "The rows have been deleted from Lake George";
print deleted`

Comment: thanks Chris, figured it was simple. Daniel, I'm a newcomer to python, just trying to tread water here, if you could give an example, I'm sure it is a great solution.